# What is the best way to use a background image on a div yet remain accessible?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I've built an image gallery that uses `div`s that contains a background image whose `size` is set to `cover`, but I am concerned about accessibility.

My questions are as follows:

1. May I use the `title` attribute on a `div` in lieu of `alt-text` attribute on an `img` tag?
2. Would adding a `figcaption` element as a sibling to the `div`, and nesting both in a `figure` element help accessibility?
3. May I use `aria-labeledby` on the `div`?
4. Should I inject the text into the `div` as well?

Thanks in advance for any insight into these questions!

Comment: Are you using background to have it cover? If so, would a javascript solution be acceptable to achive the same effect?

Answer (score 17):

You are using a `div` to show an image, then you do not use the native element.

You have to define an ARIA [`role=img`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#img) to specify that this is an image:

> In order for elements with a role of `img` be perceivable, authors MUST provide alternative text or a label determined by the [accessible name calculation](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#namecalculation).

So the best way is to do:

```
<div role="img"
     aria-label="Description of the image"
     title="Tooltip for users not using assistive technologies" />
```

Note that, as screenreaders do not always use the `title` attribute, it's preferable to use the `aria-label`.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your questions first, with potential solution at the end:

> 1. May I use the `title` attribute on a `div` in lieu of `alt`-text attribute on an `img` tag?

No. Or, more accurately, you could do that but would have little support. Since the `div` is non-interactive nor is it a landmark, there is no reason for the screen reader to give it focus and find the `title`. Further, screen reader support for `title` is poor and/or inconsistent. I recommend you look at the list PowerMapper maintains (last updated as of this writing on 16 October 2016): [*A "click here" link with TITLE attribute*](http://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/a-title/)

> 2. Would adding a `figcaption` element as a sibling to the `div`, and nesting both in a `figure` element help accessibility?

No. Screen readers do nothing with the `figcaption` (since browsers do not expose it to SR in any meaningful way).

> 3. May I use `aria-labeledby` on the div?

No. The attribute `aria-labelledby` (two “L”s) is meant for interactive content or landmarks or similar. Since the `div` is non-interactive nor is it a landmark, there is no reason for the screen reader to give it focus and find the `aria-labelledby`.

> 4. Should I inject the text into the div as well?

Yes.

Sorta.

Consider an off-screen technique for the image description, such as this one:

```
<div>
 <p class="SRonly">
  Cemetery with a lone beam of sunlight shining on a Port-A-John.
 </p>
</div>
```

The CSS might look like this (accounting for RTL languages too):

```
.SRonly {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  top: auto;
  left: -9999px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html[dir=rtl] .SRonly {
  left: inherit;
  left: unset;
  right: -9999px;
}
```

This way the "image alternative" is just flow content that will be read as the screen reader normally traverses the page. It will be hidden from sighted users. It will benefit low vision users who use a screen reader. It will not be a barrier for keyboard users who use a screen reader.

No ARIA trickery, no bastardization of your HTML to satisfy a validator, no addition of attributes that potentially reduce usability for sighted users.

You may see this in Bootstrap and other libraries as `.sr-only`. I intentionally made my example class name different.

Now, all that being said, we can test this pretty easily if you just make a Codepen and link it.

Comment: We must not forget that a lot of people needing accessibility do not use a screenreader, and that alternative text may benefit to people which can perceive the image without seeing it perfectly. (not that the `clip` property is deprecated)

Comment: Agreed and good point. For example, users in IE using Windows High Contrast Mode (WHCM) will not see the background images at all, let alone the hidden text. But [Microsoft has WHCM media queries](http://adrianroselli.com/2012/08/css-background-images-high-contrast-mode.html) that can be used to address this.

Comment: Another, more recently tested, off-screen technique: [CSS Hide-and-Seek](http://hugogiraudel.com/2016/10/13/css-hide-and-seek/)

Comment: On Windows High Contrast Mode: this has actually changed in the latest versions (of MS Edge, anyway). They now show background images, then insert a solid color background behind text spans. But give it a while before assuming that is standard.

Comment: @AmeliaBR, yep, Edge no longer hide background images. That is why I mentioned IE. IE will not change, they have decided to leave as-is. To your point, if a site sees any IE traffic then it cannot assume that background images will display.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to have alt= on the <img>.  Not only is that the established practice for accessible images but it also satisfies accessibility checker tools such as the [wave chrome extension](http://wave.webaim.org/extension/) from webaim or [axe](https://www.deque.com/products/axe/) from deque.

If you decide to use title= on the <div>, that's perfectly acceptable and is accessible but if you plan on running any accessiblity tools on your page, it'll fail because the image doesn't have an alt tag.  You'd need a blank alt=' ' on the <img> tag.