# Problem maintaining the same image size in web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, I wanted to say that I am very new to web programming.

The problem is that I am trying to create a list of properties for sale. The list should consist of a picture,title, description and a price.

Here is the page:

[image]

Here is my html code:

```
</div>

            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="T.jpg">
                    <img src="T.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
                </a>
                <h5 class="offer-item-title"><a title="детайли" href="http://www.kalchev.com/estate/offer/6309">Къща, Варна
        обл., с.Болярци</a></h5>
                <div class="offer-item-title">Триетажна къща с красива панорама към Кране Триетажна къща с красива панорама към Кране</div>
                <h4 class="offer-item-price">110 000&nbsp;€</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery">
                <a target="_blank" href="ASD.jpeg">
                    <img src="ASD.jpeg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
                </a>
                <h5 class="offer-item-title"><a title="детайли" href="http://www.kalchev.com/estate/offer/6309">Къща, Варна
        обл., с.Болярци</a></h5>
                <div class="offer-item-title">Триетажна къща с красива панорама към Кране Триетажна къща с красива панорама към Кране</div>
                <h4 class="offer-item-price">110 000&nbsp;€</h4>
            </div>
```

So the size and type of both pictures is different ( ASD.jpeg and T.jpg ). Is there anyway to create a constant image size, no matter the difference in their sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the `height` and `width` attributes from your `<img>` tag and use CSS to set the height and width of the images. I throw together a quick example for you based off the code you provided.

```css
.gallery {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 10px;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="T.jpg">
    <img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/bradybunchhouse_sc11.jpg?w=1000&h=563&crop=1" alt="Forest">
  </a>
  <h5 class="offer-item-title"><a title="детайли" href="http://www.kalchev.com/estate/offer/6309">Къща, Варна
        обл., с.Болярци</a></h5>
  <div class="offer-item-title">Триетажна къща с красива панорама към Кране Триетажна къща с красива панорама към Кране</div>
  <h4 class="offer-item-price">110 000&nbsp;€</h4>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="ASD.jpeg">
    <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--bIV3xkEm--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/jsprifdd1gmfy7e7nola.jpg" alt="Northern Lights">
  </a>
  <h5 class="offer-item-title"><a title="детайли" href="http://www.kalchev.com/estate/offer/6309">Къща, Варна
        обл., с.Болярци</a></h5>
  <div class="offer-item-title">Триетажна къща с красива панорама към Кране Триетажна къща с красива панорама към Кране</div>
  <h4 class="offer-item-price">110 000&nbsp;€</h4>
</div>
```

The part to focus on is this CSS rule:

```
.gallery img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a normal div with `background-image` property set. Something like this:

#### Instead of

```
<img src="T.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
```

#### Do this

```
<div id="myImageOne">
```

And for your css:

```
#myImageOne {
    width: 300px;                       /*Width for your image*/
    height: 300px;                      /*Height for your image*/
    background-image: url('T.jpg');     /*Your image url*/
    background-position: center center; /*Center the image in the div*/
    background-size: cover;             /*So that the whole div is filled*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;       /*Basically useless, due to background-size: cover*/
}
```

This is easier to handle most of the time. I personally ran In multiple issues with HTML `img` tag, when it comes to styling, animations and so on.

Also, this solution will handle different box sizes, image sizes, ... on its own. No need to change anything for a different image resolution, or resizing the images by hand!

If you want more information on `background-size`, check [this site out](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/).

Comment: Just something to keep in mind when using `background-image` is that you need additional code to supply the accessibility data that `<img>` provides.  You can usually get away with adding `role="image"` and `aria-label="Cutest dog in the world"` to the element with the background.  Consider: [What is the best way to use a background image on a div yet remain accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40555111/691711).

Comment: @zero298 Good addition!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not required to support Internet Explorer, you could use [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Here is an example using two images of drastically different size. They are resized to fit the `height` and `width` specified in your `<img>` tag, while maintaining proportion.

```css
img { object-fit: cover; }
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="350" height="150">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500" width="350" height="150">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add parameter to img tag , it has higher priority than style stated in css. so avoid adding width and height to img tag.